# Change organizer of outlook AppointmentItem via VSTO

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to create set of AppointmentItems from database in Outlook via  an add-in I have developed.

I would like to be able to create AppointmentItems on another exchange account's calendar(I have the credentials of it).  The organizer attribute of AppointmentItem is read-only, it did not help.

I was just wondering whether there is any way to achieve this. I am using Outlook 2010 and Visual Studi 2010

Many thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research, I have used Exchange Server Web Services api to impersonate another user and create appointments on behalf of that user.

for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that if you want to change the meeting organizer, you would need to cancel the meeting and have the new organizer send out the meeting invite. There is no way to transfer or change the organizer.

From [Outlook meeting requests: Essential do’s and don’ts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/outlook-meeting-requests-essential-dos-and-donts-HA001127678.aspx):

> If a recurring meeting is changing to a new organizer, there is not a
>   way to reassign the ownership of the meeting. The original organizer
>   should send an update with a new end date — the past meetings remain
>   on everyone’s calendars, but future occurrences after the end date are
>   removed. The new meeting organizer should send a new meeting request
>   for meetings in the future.