# Sending ical events to Outlook and making the recipient the Organizer

Tags: outlook, icalendar, vcalendar, vcal

I am trying to write an application that can manage meetings, I want to be able to send an vcal/ical event via email and have the recipient be the organizer. I have populated the organizer field with the recipients email address which does not have the required result. (in outlook 2010 at least) It appears in their calendar but it does not acknowledge them as the organizer so when trying to move the event a message is displayed notifying them that they are not the organizer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solution in the answer found here:

[Change organizer of outlook AppointmentItem via VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415048/change-organizer-of-outlook-appointmentitem-via-vsto)

You could also create appointments directly into the intended organizer's calendar using the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method, as long as you have delegate access to their mailbox.

Otherwise I do not believe there is any way to remotely set the organizer of a meeting.