# How do I create an Outlook meeting request with an alternate sender/organizer?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I've developed a Python application to automate sending emails and meeting requests for internal office events.  To keep these separate from my regular communications, we've set up an alternate email address that I can use to send the official announcements.  I've modified my application to handle this for emails by using the `SentOnBehalfOfName` for the alternate sender - however, I haven't been able to duplicate this for meeting requests.  My attempt based on a series of web searches follows.  When running this, though, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailer_test.py", line 49, in <module> test_sender)
  File "mailer_test.py", line 38, in send_meeting_request
    mtg.Send()
  File "<COMObject CreateItem>", line 2, in Send
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)
```

This happens when I add in the option for an alternate sender - removing this results in the message sent successfully from my account.  The test code which reproduces the error is below - I've removed my actual email address, but everything else is the same.

```
import win32com.client

OUTLOOK_APPOINTMENT_ITEM  = 1
OUTLOOK_MEETING           = 1
OUTLOOK_ORGANIZER         = 0
OUTLOOK_OPTIONAL_ATTENDEE = 2

ONE_HOUR       = 60
THIRTY_MINUTES = 30

OUTLOOK_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
outlook_date   = lambda dt: dt.strftime(OUTLOOK_FORMAT)

class OutlookClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    def send_meeting_request(self, subject, time, location, recipients, body,
                             sender=None):
        mtg = self.outlook.CreateItem(OUTLOOK_APPOINTMENT_ITEM)
        mtg.MeetingStatus = OUTLOOK_MEETING
        mtg.Location = location

        if sender:
            # Want to set the sender to an address specified in the call
            # This is the portion of the code that does not work
            organizer      = mtg.Recipients.Add(sender)
            organizer.Type = OUTLOOK_ORGANIZER
        for recipient in recipients:
            invitee      = mtg.Recipients.Add(recipient)
            invitee.Type = OUTLOOK_OPTIONAL_ATTENDEE

        mtg.Subject                    = subject
        mtg.Start                      = outlook_date(time)
        mtg.Duration                   = ONE_HOUR
        mtg.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = THIRTY_MINUTES
        mtg.ResponseRequested          = False
        mtg.Body                       = body
        mtg.Send()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import datetime
    ol = OutlookClient()
    meeting_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
    test_recipients = ['me@example.com']
    test_sender     = 'alternate@example.com'

    ol.send_meeting_request('Test Meeting', meeting_time, 'Nowhere',
                            test_recipients, 'This is a test meeting.',
                            test_sender)
```

Note: This is not the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415048/change-organizer-of-outlook-appointmentitem-via-vsto), since I'm not using C# and I'm also not trying to edit the meeting request after the fact.

**Update:**
As Marnix Klooster suggested, I've been looking through the UI to see how I can do this, and it doesn't appear to be easy (if even possible).  The one way I have done it is to go into the other user's calendar and create a new appointment there and add invitees.  That mailbox is added by going to the `Advanced` tab from the `More Settings...` button in the Server Settings dialog displayed when changing the `Account Settings`.  An alternate answer to this question would be how to use this mailbox as the default originator when accessing Outlook via COM.

Comment: Just to ask a dumb question: Is this functionality available through the UI? If not (and I've never found it), then it might just be impossible programmatically as well.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all - I've been trying it through the UI without much luck.  However, http://help.lockergnome.com/office/set-meeting-organizer--ftopict697177.html seems to think that it's possible by messing with PR_RECIPIENT_FLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/manage-another-person-s-mail-and-calendar-items-HA010075092.aspx#BM5), you can send meeting requests on behalf of another person, but you need to have access to that person's calendar. The other person must appoint you as a delegate.

Comment: That's correct.  The first step given there is to "Open the other person's calendar."  I can do that manually, but is there a way to automate that?

Comment: Using the exchange API: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/exchange.html?